# Error al Procesar la Petición Código de error: 200

Tags: phpmyadmin

we  have  centos 7 recently  installed,  and lamp  configuration

phpMyAdmin  was  working  well   but some  day  no working  more ,  every option  i try to  use   respond  with

Error al Procesar la Petición
Código de error: 200

please help  us !

Comment: Can you provide an English version of the error message?

Comment: Check your webserver error logs for any hints.

Comment: @Grice: The complete error message is:
"Error in Processing Request
Error code: 200
Error text: OK."

I have the same error while trying to insert more than 10 rows at the same time.